# Test function which requires *os.File as argument

Tags: go

I would like to write a test for the bellow function, but I can't understand what I can send as an argument to `toCount`, because I don't want to open/create a file, I know that os.Stdin will work, but I think you're not allowed to write into it.

```
func toCount(f *os.File) int {
  input := buffo.NewScanner(f)
  sum := 0;
  for input.Scan() {
    sum++
  }
  return sum
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `toCount` function only requires an `io.Reader`. If you change the signature to

```
func toCount(f io.Reader) int
```

It can accept an `*os.File` and any other kind of reader you want to use to test.

Comment: So basically anything that has `Read(p []byte) (n int, err error)` can be passed?

Comment: @alex: yes. That kind of the whole point of go interfaces: https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#interfaces. You really need to understand them in order to use go. http://tour.golang.org/methods/4

Comment: I just wanted to make sure, the problem is that I don't know how to find in the standard lib everything that will satisfy that interface besides taking them one by one, or how did you know that os.File is satisfying io.Reader?

Comment: @alex: It will quickly become very obvious when something implements the common interfaces, like those in `io`. There are so many things that implement `io.Reader`, it's not really useful to try and list them all. Plus even is `io.Reader` wasn't available, you could declare your own reader interface to accept the types you need.